# How to fit a curve only until its maximum?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I'm struggling to find a smart way to fit a curve (I use `curve_fit`, shown below) until its maximum has been reached without having to manipulate the initial arrays.

```
def f_singlecomponent(x, f0, a, k):
    return f0 + a * (1 - np.exp( -k * x ))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f_singlecomponent, coords[n][0], coords[n][1], p0=init_vals)
```

Comment: As I recall, curve_fit() does not change the data passed to it. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: No, I try to find a way to fit curves that can be described with a*(1-exp(-k*t)) but after the plateau has been reached, the curve drops and this drop should not be fitted.

Comment: Maybe you pass an `sigma`-array as well, setting all values below the maximum to one and all above to `numpy.infty`. I did not check, but maybe `curve_fit` works with masked arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple sigma-mask as mentioned in my comment above results in

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func( x, a, k, y0):
    return a * ( 1- np.exp( -k * x ) ) + y0

def mymask( y ):
    m = np.argmax(y)
    l = len(y)
    return m * [1] + ( l - m )* [ np.infty ]

xlist = np.linspace( 0., 10., 100 )
ylist = np.fromiter( ( func( x, 1.3, .44, 8 ) for x in xlist ), np.float )
ylist2 = np.fromiter( ( func( x, 1.3, .44, 8 ) * ( 0.5 * ( 1 - np.tanh( (x - 7 ) ) ) *.13 + 1-.13 ) for x in xlist ), np.float )

popt_o, _ = curve_fit(func, xlist, ylist, p0=[1.3,.44,8])
popt_w, _ = curve_fit(func, xlist, ylist2, p0=[1.3,.44,8],  maxfev=9000 )
popt_t, _ = curve_fit(func, xlist, ylist, p0=[1.3,.44,8], sigma=mymask( ylist ))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( xlist, ylist, linewidth=3 )
ax.plot( xlist, ylist2 )
ax.plot( xlist, np.fromiter( ( func( x,*popt_o ) for x in xlist ), np.float ), ls='--', linewidth=2 )
ax.plot( xlist, np.fromiter( ( func( x,*popt_t ) for x in xlist ), np.float ), ls=':', linewidth=1 )
ax.plot( xlist, np.fromiter( ( func( x,*popt_w ) for x in xlist ), np.float ) )
plt.show()
```

which looks like[image],

which seems quite Okey to me.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!